# Not able to Pull from database and display in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Him I'm trying to pull the max value from a row to display it in a alert message. But It gives 2 errors ..

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Access denied for user 'SYSTEM'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 20

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 20
```

please Help

```
<html>
 <title> Test</title>
  <head> 

  </head>
  <body>
 <form method="POST" action="">
  <h1>Button to display data</h1>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="PULL">
  </form>
  </body>

 <?php 
   $no=20;

   if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    include ('airlineDB2.php');
     {

     $select=mysql_query("select MAX(ticketno) from ticketbook");

       print '<script type="text/javascript">';
        print 'alert("The no is '.  $select.' is already registered")';
         print '</script>';  
     }     
   ?>

   </html>
```

THIS is the connection code to the database
and i have saved it as airlineDB2.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dberror1 = "Could not connect to database";
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser,$dbpass) or die ($drerror1);
$selectdb = mysql_select_db('airlinedb') or die ($drerror1);
?>
```

Comment: check your `airlineDB2.php`, you are not connected to database.

Comment: when i open it in localhost\airlineDB2.php it works

Comment: What does it work? It should connect you to database.

Comment: it's definitely because connect to database. double check your database user and host .

Comment: yes ..if i open it in localhost i get a blank screen which i was told happens if the database is successfully connected .

Comment: Have you tried with `$select=mysql_query("select MAX(ticketno) from ticketbook", $link);`?

Answer (score 0):

Connection to database does not work. You have a typo, that's why you don't see the error:

```
$dberror1 = "Could not connect to database";
```

but later on you use

```
$link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser,$dbpass) or die ($drerror1);
```

**$dberror1** != **$drerror1**

Comment: so how do i fix it ?... but other codes works when i insert into database and pull ect .. only this code does not work...

Comment: But error says: `Access denied for user 'SYSTEM'@'localhost'`, which means you are not connected, specially not as `root`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$no=20;
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
include ('airlineDB2.php');
{
```

make the include after the curly bracket